# How can I select internal fields of CDC JSON to be Key of record in Kafka using SMT?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have tried using SMT configuration ValueToKey and ExtractField$Key for my following CDC JSON data. But as id field is internal it is giving me an error as field is not recognized. How can I make it accessible to internal fields ?

```
"before": null,
"after": {
  "id": 4,
  "salary": 5000
},
"source": {
  "version": "1.5.0.Final",
  "connector": "mysql",
  "name": "Try-",
  "ts_ms": 1623834752000,
  "snapshot": "false",
  "db": "mysql_db",
  "sequence": null,
  "table": "EmpSalary",
  "server_id": 1,
  "gtid": null,
  "file": "binlog.000004",
  "pos": 374,
  "row": 0,
  "thread": null,
  "query": null
},
"op": "c",
"ts_ms": 1623834752982,
"transaction": null
}
```

Configuration Used:

```
transforms=createKey,extractInt
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields=id
transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractInt.field=id
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately accessing nested fields is not possible without using a different transform.

If you want to use the built-in ones, you'd need to [extract the after state before you can access its fields](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/configuration/event-flattening.html)

```yaml
transforms=extractAfterState,createKey,extractInt

# Add these
transforms.extractAfterState.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
# since you cannot get the ID from null events
transforms.extractAfterState.drop.tombstones=true 

transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields=id
transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractInt.field=id
```

Comment: So you mean after extraction of after state I need to do transformations using KStreams or KSQL? It is not possible to set the key for such nested JSON in the fly, do you mean it?

Comment: It's not possible with `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey`. I didn't say its not possible with a different transform, if one exists, or a combination of transforms

Comment: And where to find such transform, many people are asking... As for me it is required for tombstone handling. I need to extract field from `payload.after` if it is not tombstone and from `payload.before` if it is tombstone.

Comment: @RafisGaneev I think to do logic like that, then you must [write your own](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
  transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
    transforms.extractInt.field=id
   
    key.converter.schemas.enable=false
    value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

With these transformations and changes in properties file. I could make it possible.